# CMIS - Searching list properties

Tags: java, apache, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

With CMIS I can add a property to an object. The property can have one value or it can be a multi-value property. When you have a multi-value property on a number of objects, how do you search for all objects  that has this property and the property contains a specific value or a number of specific values?

For example. (Example taken from [here](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-update.html))

```
CmisObject cmisobject = ....

Map<String, Object> updateProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

List<String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<String>();
shoppingList.add("milk");
shoppingList.add("bread");
shoppingList.add("cheese");
updateProperties.put("my:shopping.list", shoppingList); // multi-value property

cmisobject.updateProperties(updateProperties);
```

Now, if I wish to perform a query for all objects that has the property **my:shopping.list** and where the property contains the value **bread** or the values **milk AND cheese**, how would I do this?

Comment: What happens if you do a cmis query like `my:shopping.list = "bread" OR (my:shopping.list = "cheese" and my:shopping.list = "milk")` - does that not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean isPropertyPresent(Map<String, Object> updateProperties) {//should use List<String> instead of Object
    List<String> shoppingList = (List<String>) updateProperties.get("my:shopping.list");
    if (shoppingList != null) {
         return shoppingList.contains("bread") || (shoppingList.contains("milk") && shoppingList.contains("cheese"));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This solution means first retrieving all of the repositories objects, and then iterating over them to identify the specific objects I'm interested in. If I have a repository with tens of thousands of objects I would need to retrieve ALL of them first, making this a very impractical solution.

Comment: if you dont have duplicate then use HashSet instead of list and that would mean you could say contains with O(1)